# Identifying max-content width

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

Suppose my div have a css property **max-content** and its width changes based on the content within. I want to detect the changes in size. Is that possible? Or Can I get the max-content width for any element beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

one way to listen to the dimension change of a particular element by attaching an [**onresize**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp) event listener to the element.

**Note**: One should be careful while using such events as it can be very heavy and can result in multiple reflow which is not healthy for a website.

Comment: onresize can be expensive and I am looking for an alternative